# How to import txt file with delimiter | without editing the file?

Tags: sql, ssh, phpmyadmin, delimiter, delimited

data.txt

```
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|USA|TRANSIT|MEMBER|0|0.065|45.915
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|ASIA|DIRECT|MEMBER|172|10.400|32.899
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|USA|CANCEL|GUEST|0|0.605|25.346
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|AFRICA|CANCEL||GUEST|5|0.010|43.733
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|USA|CANCEL|BOOKED|0|0.210|69.208
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|ASIA|TRANSIT|MEMBER|0|0.265|31.583
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|ASIA|DIRECT|MEMBER|0|0.280|89.905
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|AUSTRALIA|CANCEL|GUEST|0|0.250|27.438
2015-06-18|2|PARIS|EUROPE|ASIA|DIRECT|GUEST|6|0.020|17.966
```

I need to import to SQL without any changes inside data.txt. I read from some tutorial that `|` needs to be changed to `,` first, but I don't have access to edit data.txt.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

No need to change anything in Data.txt, by using sql server import wizard you can set the delimiter as  **"|"**

Kindly check the following screen shot of SQL server import wizard where you can set the delimiter.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need tutorial for linux server.

Comment: i use xampp ( phpmyadmin,mysql) for test
and i use linux server with user ssh account ( real server )
my database use text file ( .txt )